# How to set or get JavaScript multiple cookies based on html ids?

Tags: javascript, cookies, vs-web-site-project

I made a blog application which has many articles. I want to set cookies for articles which user click . So that user can see which articles he/she visited or read.  I am not storing cookies on backend. Cookies are set based on articles id

Answer (score 0):

first of all **welcome** to StackOverflow

From your question, you can even leverage the `localStorage` for that no? There's no point to use only Cookies, but all you would need to do is:

- for each page reload, append that page to an Array
- if you want to get that value, read the array

with time, you would want to add a couple more things

- only store the last 10 visited pages (so you don't end up with 100 links)
- don't repeat pages

adding to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is a bit simpler than cookies, as you can just do `window.localStorage.setItem(key, payload)`...

and you would read as `var links = window.localStorage.getItem(key)`

**remember** that, just like cookies, you need to save as a string, doing `.setItem('links', { a: 1 })` will endup saving `[Object Object]`

---

if you have something like:

```js
var linksStorage = {
  KEY: 'visitedLinks',
  get: () => {
    var allLinks = window.localStorage.getItem(this.KEY)
    return JSON.parse(allLinks || '[]') // parse string or start with empty array
  },
  savePage: () => {
    var allLinks = this.localStorage.get()     // get all existing links
    allLinks.push({                            // append this page info
      id: window.location.query, 
      page: window.location.pathname
    })
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      this.KEY, JSON.stringify(allLinks))      // save back
  }
}
```

then a simple:

```js
window.linksStorage.savePage()
```

will append the current page to the list, and when you need to read:

```js
window.linksStorage.get()
```

will give you the list as an Array object

---

Added after comments

```js
var writeCookies = () => {
  var allCookies = window.document.cookie.split('; ') // split them all
  document.write("<ul>")
  allCookies.forEach(c => { // for each cookie
    var info = c.split('=') // name and value
    document.write(`<li><b>${info[0]}</b> -> ${info[1]}`)
  })
  document.write("</ul>")
}
```

and execute as `writeCookies()`

Comment: I know how to set it but how to get multiple cookies for multiple articles user visited  which has different article Id. cookies= id = value. Where id is articles id. For example 1= visited. 4=visited 7=visited. How to retrieve this cookies and display it below articles

Comment: why are you using multiple cookies? why don't you add all in just one cookie? so if I read 20 articles I would have 20 cookies? careful with the new Cookies browser protection systems... you should simple, as I wrote, keep all data in a single, either cookie or localStorage item

Comment: Ok 1 Cookie file. And I store it like article Id=value. Example 1 =visited, 30=visited etc. How to retrieve it and and assign it. Example <div id=1>article1 {visited}<\div> <div id=2>article30 {visited}</div>

Comment: then your question is something different from what you asking on this one ... but with my code, you get an array of links, all you need to do is `window.linksStorage.get()
.forEach(link => { ... })` and write how you want into the DOM.

Comment: Can you show the get cookies code. Foreach(Id in cookies){document.wrte(id)=message}

Comment: the variable `window.document.cookie` has all cookies as a string, this `window.document.cookie.split('; ')` will give you all as an array. All you need is to parse that, as I said, it's not as easy as work with `localStorage`. I would recommend that you use a cookie library so it makes the hard work for you

Comment: That means I cannot iterate through cookies and compare using html id

Comment: It's added the code to read the cookies, you can test in the browser, just open console, paste the code and execute, and then run `writeCookies()` - REMEMBER that is a VERY simple code, does not care about cookie domains and cookie paths... please use a framework to read cookies for that, if using jQuery, use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Comment: var keyValuePairs = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.length; i++) {
    var name = keyValuePairs[i].substring(0, keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('=')); document.getElementbyid(name)=something
    var value = keyValuePairs[i].substring(keyValuePairs[i].indexOf('=')+1);
} What do you think of this code